# facebook sdk 4.17 iOS sending gift with FBSDKGameRequestContent

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk-4.0

Hi I am using Facebook sdk 4.17 in my iOS app.

I am trying to send a gift with FBSDKGameRequestContent and I get 2 different errors with 2 different gifts while I am sending from the same code:

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];

gameRequestContent.message = @"Your gift is waiting for you";
gameRequestContent.title = @"Choose Friends";
gameRequestContent.recipients = recipentsToSend;
gameRequestContent.objectID = collection_item;
gameRequestContent.actionType = FBSDKGameRequestActionTypeSend ;

// Assuming self implements <FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate>
FBSDKGameRequestDialog* dialog = [[FBSDKGameRequestDialog alloc] init];
dialog.content = gameRequestContent;
dialog.delegate = self;
[dialog show];
```

gift 1 error 1:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=The objectID is required when the actionType is either send or askfor., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentNameKey=objectID}

gift 2 error 2:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=100 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Parameter object_id: Invalid id: "ChristmasHomeOrnament"}

Anyone have any idea?